# Deleting an undeleted LQP review reports deletions incorrectly

Tags: bug, low-quality-posts, deleted-answers

So we have [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413105/calling-delete-method-in-web-api/42569312#42569312) (10k+ if that wasn't obvious). The chain of events here is

1. The answer was [reported as LQP and deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15400968)
2. The [user then undeleted their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42569312/timeline#history_971ca62f-6991-4687-9882-3583da6b0511) (which [is sometimes possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182746), not the issue here)
3. 3x 20k+ users [deleted the answer again](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42569312/timeline#history_0a143279-780d-4b7c-924b-db85aeaead1e)

This can be seen from [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42569312/revisions)

This is how it looks now

[image]

The timestamp is correct, but those are the original LQP reviewers, not the 20k users (myself included) who did the deed the second time.

Comment: Getting a bit of deja vu here that this has come up somewhere before...

Comment: Anyway - I've tried a quick undelete/delete on it and it hasn't shifted the deleted from review note either.

Comment: @JonClements I thought so too, but was unable to find one on Meta. Didn't check Meta.SE tho

Comment: select top 1, users from PostHistory where votetodelete?

Comment: afaik, This is [meta-tag:status-by-design]. There is an auto flag raised whenever the OP undeletes the post after the review queue has deleted it. Once a moderator or 3 20k users delete it, it shows that the post was deleted from review. Earlier this wasn't the case, it used to show "deleted xxx minutes ago", this one is quite new.